# Как настроить хостинг подпапки?

Tags: php, apache, сервер, хостинг, ispmanager

Сервер управляется через ISPManager. Сайт на PHP. По умолчанию он создает папку с названием сайта и ее хостит, но надо хостить вложенную папку web (сайт на yii2). Пытался через htaccess, но ничего не вышло, а в интерфейсе я не нахожу возможности указать папку которую хостить.

Comment: когда домен в ISPManager создаете, там указывается корневая папка. вот там и проишите `web` директорию

Comment: @teran указал, но кажется не помогло. Сейчас выдает "сайт выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз"

Comment: может свои старания из htacess убрать надо? )

Comment: @teran я вообще удалил из корня htaccess. Но он ведь туда и не должен заходить если хостится папка web. А в папке web у меня стандартный для yii2 htaccess:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]`

Comment: смотрите что за редиректы выполняются. ф12 и вкладку network. откуда и куда 30x-редиректы у вас там идут?

Comment: @teran хмм, редиректит на страницу /login, с нее на главную и по кругу... Странно, на локалке когда разрабатывал такого не было.

Comment: У меня все-таки подозрение что это apache редиректит. Может что-то с https?